# Is it possible to save an array or class to $_POST?

Tags: php, wordpress, post

I have a meta box plugin which I am working on in wordpress. I have a button, with which you may add inputs, which can be either text areas or text inputs. When the user updates their post, whatever is in the text boxes and inputs is saved to the post meta, however I'd like to loop through the inputs and add subjective data to the post for each one.

for example, at the moment I just save the value of all the inputs to my 'BBPlugin-resources' key, one after the other, like so:

```
 'a:2:{
        i:0;s:6:"some words";
        i:1;s:14:"some more words";
    }'
```

I guess the closest thing I know about is json, where the following kind of script would exist, but I don't know if it's possible with post meta. in any case, I'd like to be able to have something like this:

```
 'a:2:{
        "title": "a metabox full of inputs";
        "input boxes"{
            "input 1"{
                "text": "some words",
                "type:"textarea"
            };
            "input 2"{
                "text": "some more words",
                "type:"input"
            };
        };
    }'
```

is such a thing possible?

Comment: $_POST itself an array.

Comment: is it possible to save an array within in then?

Comment: Yes. You can set one array to another array.

Comment: it is called mutidimensional array

Comment: Thanks, please enter that into an answer and I'll mark it off

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create array from this

I suppose you get the type of input in `$_POST['input_type']` nd actual input in `$_POST['input_text']`

```
$input_data = array(
                    'title'         => "a metabox full of inputs",
                    'input_boxes'   => array(
                        'text'  => $_POST['input_text'],
                        'type'  => $_POST['input_type'],
                        ),
                );

//for getting multiple entries under input_boxes run a foreach loop of all text boxes and text area and get them in single array
// for eg : $inpur_arr and put it in the key 'input_boxes' =>  $inpur_arr
/* else 'input_boxes'   => array(
                        'text'  => $_POST['input_text'],
                        'type'  => $_POST['input_type'],
                        ),*/



//will save the json encoded data
update_post_meta($post_ID, 'input_json', json_encode($input_data));

//wil save the serialized data as shown in your example above
update_post_meta($post_ID, 'input_json', $input_data);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot

Comment: will $_POST['input_text'] return the value of an input with the name(not id) of input_text?

Comment: yes $_POST['input_text'] where 'input_text' is the name of input field

Comment: ok, one last question; is the value the only thing you can obtain this way? for example, could I get the id of the div in question?

Comment: for what pupose you need the ID .. i guess you might be thinking to get the input type by its ID

Comment: yeah, I would set the type as the id, or maybe the class

Comment: Nope you only get the value from the name .. you can do one thing create a hidden field for the inputs containing their type and get their types by the hidden input name

Comment: everything is working so far, however I'm having trouble retreving data from the arrays. if I try to echo BBPlugin-resources[0][0] for example, I get null

Comment: nevermind, I was using the key instead of the identifier. Thanks for all the help! you're a lifesaver